# How to connect to Libreoffice Base OR MS-Access database from Angular based Electron app?

Tags: angular, ms-access, electron, ado, libreoffice-base

I am developing an ERP desktop app in Electron using Angular

We decided to use Libreoffice base OR Ms-access to store the user stocks and transactions

The base / ms-access file will be bundled along with electron

Now my problem is I want to connect to the Base OR MS-access via Angular modules

**How to connect via an Angular App to Base or MS-access ?**

And I am asking both Access and Base because ... Since the app have to run on Linux and Mac OS , I doubt whether Access Data Access Components are compatible with Linux and Mac OS.

Older Stackoverflow answers suggest that ADO not compatible with linux.

That's why I am also asking about Libreoffice Base ..

Please help me .